# How to fix 404 error when accessing a SPA (Storage Account) using Azure Front Door Premium?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, single-page-application, azure-front-door

I am using **Azure Front Door Premium** to serve two applications under the same domain - an Azure App Service and a Single Page Application (SPA) stored in Azure Storage Account. I want to serve the App Service using the root URL (mydomain.com) and the SPA using a path (mydomain.com/spa).

I have already configured routes for both applications in Azure Front Door. For the App Service, I have used "`/*`" in the "Patterns to match" option, and for the SPA, I have used "`/spa`" and "`/spa/*`" in the same option. However, I am getting 404 errors when trying to access the SPA using the path (mydomain.com/spa).

I have tried to configure a rule to fix this issue, but it is not working. The rule I used is:

[image]

How to fix this issue and serve the SPA from the desired path using Azure Front Door Premium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure storage account fails to recognize the configured patterns to match in the route, causing the SPA to be unable to route mydomain.com/spa to <storage_account_container>/$web/index.html.

[Front Door Service - URL rewrite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-url-rewrite?pivots=front-door-standard-premium)

The solution required two changes.

- For URL rewrite source pattern, only the path after the route configuration “patterns to match” is considered. For example, you have the following incoming URL format `<Frontend-domain>/<route-patterns-to-match-path>/<Rule-URL-Rewrite-Source-pattern>`, only `/<Rule-URL-Rewrite-Source-pattern>` will be considered by the rule engine as the source pattern to be rewritten.
  [image]
- For scenarios, where `/<route-patterns-to-match-path` segment of the URL path must be removed, set the Origin path of the Origin group in route configuration to `/`.
  [image]

as a result:

```
**Azure App Service** 
URL: mydomain.com 
(Route) Pattern to Match: "/*"
(Route) Origin Path: ""

**SPA Storage Account**
URL: mydomain.com/spa
(Route) Pattern to Match: "/spa, /spa/*"
(Route) Origin Path: "/"
Rule: / -> index.html
```